# Eclipse Auto Generate Doxygen Comments Configuration

Tags: c++, eclipse, doxygen

It seems Eclipse has Doxygen support somewhat natively now.  Go to C/C++ -> Editors -> Documentation Tool Comments: Doxygen.

However it appears to only act on /** */ comments for auto generating.

In our project we use triple slash /// to generate doxygen comments.

It seems there is no way to configure Doxygen comment generation in Eclipse.  Any tips?  Is there a config file we can alter?  Some way to force it.

Comment: Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4403192/623518? Does this answer your question?

Comment: It unfortunately does not, it is the same issue though roughly.

Comment: Just a note, Documentation tool comments is on the Editor page, it's not a sub node under Editor like I initially thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old question but it's better to add a fresh answer, currently eclipse cdt 9.10 in 2019-12 fully support /// and //! styles, in 2020-03 has been added few options to customize doxygen behavior

Comment: How, where? some more explanation might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately as of posting this answer there is no solution.  The doxygen comment style is apparently hard coded in Eclipse Juno and previous.  You can see a bug report here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333134

There are workarounds but none support the auto doxygen comments generated in eclipse by merely typing '///[enter]'.  See here for some attempts: [Change doxygen comment style in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403192/change-doxygen-comment-style-in-eclipse)

A C++ code template is a good attempt but leaves a lot to be desired.

Until this changes this is the accepted answer.

Comment: This is fixed in the latest version(neon) of Eclipse.

Comment: @Crusher the bug is still open and doxygen style still not configurable in eclipse Oxygen (one version newer)?