# Does Eclipse CDT support backslash as tag for Doxygen?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, doxygen

I was wondering whether or not Eclipse CDT supports the inclusion of Doxygen tag in the old fashion C style. And , if so, how to modify it.

I mean instead of having JavaDoc tagging

```
/**
 * @brief 
 *
 * @param 
 * @param 
 * @param 
 * @return 
 */
```

I could use

```
/**
 * \brief 
 *
 * \param 
 * \param 
 * \param 
 * \return 
 */
```

EDIT: adding current Eclipse CDT Editor settings  for documentation

> Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (includes Incubating components)
>
> Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0) Build id: 20201210-1552

[image]

Comment: What happens if you uncheck "Use javadoc style for tags"? I don't have this option here.

Comment: Then I get somewhat I was looking for! `/**
 * \fn
 * \brief 
 * 
 * \param 
 */`

Comment: I know you don't have control in CDT on the comment format, but at least your tags a no more in JavaDoc style.

Answer (score 2):

It does. You can activate Doxygen documentation support by going to the `Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor` preference window. At the bottom you have an option called *Documentation tool comments*. Set *Workspace default* to "Doxygen" instead of "None". When this is done, you can use both kinds of tags, which will be understood by Eclipse CDT.

For now, it is not possible to customize the way doxygen comments are formatted (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403192/change-doxygen-comment-style-in-eclipse?rq=1)). In recent versions, you seem to have some very limited control, however, in the form of a couple options below the *Workspace default* option mentionned above. One of those is: *Use javadoc style for tags*. Uncheck it to get backslash style tags.

Comment: I had that feature enable, see updated OP. Every time I type `/**+enter` I get the `@brief` instead of `\brief`